# JQuery won't execute on Chrome Extension Content Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Here, I have the simplest of chrome extensions. I noticed that the JQuery does not seem to be executing in my content script. However, normal javascript works just fine. I'm wondering what could be preventing the JQuery from executing.

manifest

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "test",
    "background": {
    "scripts": ["popup.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "js": ["jquery.js", "content.js"]
    }]
}
```

popup.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (response, sender, 
    sendResponse)
{
    alert("test");
    alert(response.test.toString());
});
```

content script

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({test: 
    $(".chapters").first().innerHTML.toString()}, function(response){});

//document.getElementsByClassName("chapters")[0].innerHTML.toString()} works 
just fine
```

Comment: I assume `jquery.js` is in the same location as `content.js`?

Comment: Yes, it is in the same folder.

Comment: jQuery doesn't have innerHTML property. Use `.html()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery doesn't have innerHTML property. Use .html() is the answer.